# Laravel routes with multiple slugs won't work in React

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, react-router, laravel-routing

I have an application with a Laravel back-end/React.js front-end. I am using react router so to make that work I have any path pointing to the Controller which loads the view with the components in them. However when I add nested routes in the react side i.e. "blog/:blogId", it seems that it completely skips the tag in which components are loaded into and shows me content from the Laravel view instead.

I originally had:

```
`Route::get('/{slug?}', 'ProjectsController@index'`
```

I've tried:

```
`Route::any('{path}', function($path){
    $projects = Project::all();
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('welcome', compact('projects', 'posts'));
})->where('path', '.*');`
```

This won't work either:

```
`Route::get('/{slug?}/{id?}', 'ProjectsController@index'`
```

What I want is for both `/blog` and /`blog/2` to go to `ProjectsController@index` which loads the view with the react tag.

The data in my index function in ProjectsController is:

```
  `$projects = Project::all();
    $posts = Post::all();

    //return $projects;
    return view('welcome', compact('projects', 'posts'));`
```

Has anyone come across this before? Thanks.

**UPDATED:**

The welcome view being returned by the controller index method:

The `<div id="content"></div>` is where my base component is being loaded into. So when navigating to route '/blog' I see my component, when navigating to '/blog/anything' I see Laravel's login and register links.

```
`@extends('layout')

@section('content')

    @if (Route::has('login'))
        <div class="top-right links">
            @if (Auth::check())
                <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
            @else
                <a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
                <a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
            @endif
        </div>
    @endif

<div id="content"></div>

@include('partials._scripts')

@endsection`
```

The component making use of the link:

```
`<a href={`/blog/${item.id}`} target="_blank">View here</a>

                    <Route path="/blog/:blogId" component={Post} />`
```

My other routes in the base component:

```
`<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" render={(props)=> <Home text={text} mobileNavIsOpen={hamburgerOpen} backgroundImage={background}/>} />
<Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
<Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
<Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>`
```

I've tried placing the /blog/:blogId route in the base app along with the others - still no difference.

**UPDATE:**

When removing the /blog/ route tag from react router and just keeping '/blog/:blogId, it has the same effect.

**UPDATE/PARTLY SOLVED:**

Adding `(\\d+)` to my react router path: path={`/blog/:id(\\d+)`} rightly took me to the nested component. It did also load the blade view content, however, so as a temporary fix I have taken out the blade content that was displayed. Would be good to see if anyone has another way around it. Thanks.

Comment: Why you need react route If you want blog/:blogId handles by laravel route?

Comment: Hi @aseferov, its not that I want it handled by laravel route, its that I need to direct any paths including their subpaths to the view handling my component in order for react to work. Thus if I want blog:/blogId, I need to tell laravel routes to also direct these paths to the view.

Comment: Please add view part where you navigate user blog/:blogId in component

Comment: @aseferov please see updated above

Comment: You need change <a href={`/blog/${item.id}`} target="_blank">View here</a> to react Link component <Link to={`/blog/${item.id}`}

Comment: @aseferov Regardless of this, navigating manually to the route via the browser should be taking me to the correct component if my <Route> tag is set up correctly. I've changed it to use Link anyway but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'ProjectController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

This is basically added to the end of the routes/web.php, since most probably you are trying to build a SPA and you want all http requests to be handled by react router.

Update:
Based on your updates I understand that you want both `/blog` and `/blog/:ID` to be handled by the same method. That can be done like this

```
Route::get('blog/{id?}', 'ProjectController@index')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

If you need the ID in the index method give it as the first argument to the method and send it to the view.

Comment: This gives me the same result, it will only work when I return data within the controller method but not when I return a view. When I return a view and navigate to /blog/2 it brings back the blade.php data. When I return a view and navigate to just /blog, it loads the front-end component. 

Please see updated question above with whats in my controller function.

Comment: I've tried the suggested updated method - same result, I've even passed down the id to the component and specifically told it to navigate to /blog/id, id being the variable from the controller but nothing.